# How add various functions within 1 conditional?

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

I want to add some gravity forms filters in my functions.php. I have the code up and running, but I would like to improve this snippet with a condition. As I only need these filters on 1 page of my website, it doesn't make sense for it to run site-wide.
I'm not a programmer. I tried a couple of ways to put this code snippet under the condition: "if (is_page( array( 'post-form' ) ) ) {" but without success. I know it's possible to add this conditional inside each function, but that doesn't look very good, and I'd like more optimized code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_rich_text_editor_buttons_17', 'gravityfpega_botoestiny', 10, 2 );
function gravityfpega_botoestiny() {
    $mce_buttons = array( 'formatselect', 'bold', 'italic', 'bullist', 'numlist', 'blockquote', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'link', 'unlink', 'spellchecker' ); // Enable only Bold, Italic and Bullet List buttons
    return $mce_buttons;
}
add_filter( 'gform_rich_text_editor_buttons_row_two_17', 'gravityfpega_botoestiny2', 10, 2 );
function gravityfpega_botoestiny2() {
    $mce_buttons = array( 'strikethrough', 'hr', 'forecolor', 'removeformat', 'charmap', 'outdent', 'indent', 'undo', 'redo', 'wp_help' ); // Enable only Bold, Italic and Bullet List buttons
    return $mce_buttons;
}
function gravityfpega_mediatinymce( $editor_settings, $field_object, $form, $entry ) {
    $editor_settings['media_buttons'] = true;
    $editor_settings['editor_height'] = 600;
    return $editor_settings;
}
add_filter( 'gform_rich_text_editor_options_17', 'gravityfpega_mediatinymce', 10, 4 );
function gravityfpega_dragdroptinymce( $editor_settings, $field_object, $form, $entry ) {
    $editor_settings['drag_drop_upload'] = true;
    return $editor_settings;
}
//loads script to do the oembed stuff
function alt_lab_front_end_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_editor();        
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mce-view', '', array('tiny_mce') ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alt_lab_front_end_scripts' );
add_filter( 'gform_rich_text_editor_options_17', 'gravityfpega_dragdroptinymce', 10, 4 );
add_filter( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_excerpt', 'enable_excerpt', 10, 1 );
function enable_excerpt( $enable_excerpt ){
    return true;
} }
// https://gravitywiz.com/automatic-save-and-continue-with-gravity-forms
if ( class_exists( 'GW_Save_Continue_Auto_Load' ) ) {
    new GW_Save_Continue_Auto_Load( array(
        'form_ids'                   => array( 17 ),
        'enable_inline_confirmation' => true,
        'auto_save'                  => true
    ) );
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Is `post-form` the slug for the page?  The parameter for `is_page()` should be "the page ID, title, slug, or array of such".  When you say "without success", what was the failure?

Comment: I believe your issue in this situation is due to the order of operations in WordPress.  The functions file is executed early in the process and `is_page()` will not return an accurate T/F until much later.